# Comparing 2 images intensities

Tags: image, matlab

I have two images 1 and 2. I want to get the v (intensity) value of the hsv images; then I want the v (intensity) value of the first image equal to v (intesity) value of the second image?

I used this code to get the v

```
v = image1(:, :, 3);
u = image2(:, :, 3);
```

How do I make both u and v the same value?

Thanks,

Comment: `image1(:, :, 3) = u`? Though I have no idea why you'd want to do that. I think you need to clarify your question, but I suspect that you're looking for something closer to histogram equalization.

Comment: Its because i had two images of the same scene that are taken at different times, therefore the two images will have different intensities. So now i want to equalise their intesities so they look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely sounds like you want to do some kind of histogram equalization. As a first attempt you can try Matlab's [histeq](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html) function. (You should also read the documentation for [imhist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html).) To make the intensity values in `image1` more closely match those in `image2` (they will almost certainly never become identical) you would do something like this:

```
v = image1(:, :, 3);
u = image2(:, :, 3);
targetHist = imhist(u);
newV = histeq(v, targetHist);
newImage1 = cat(3, image1(:, :, 1), image1(:, :, 2), newV);
    % or, alternatively %
image1(:, :, 3) = newV;
```

If this technique doesn't give you the results you need, there are other methods of histogram equalization that you can use, including adaptive techniques that equalize intensities by regions.

#### Edit:

Here's a little about what the code is doing. For more information you can look at the Algorithm section of the link to `histeq` I gave above.

Given a reference image (in this case `image2`) in HSV format, we're taking the Value channel (or Intensity, or Brightness channel) and using `imhist` to divide the intensity levels in the image into 256 bins (by default), with each bin containing the number of pixels that have that intensity value.

`histeq` in this usage actually does [histogram matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching). It calculates the histogram for the second image and tries to "match" the input histogram. For instance, if the histogram has all of the bins empty except for bin 100, which has 300 pixels, and your image has all of the bins empty except for bin 80, which has 300 pixels, `histeq` will increase the intensity of each pixel in the image by 20. A very simplistic example, but hopefully you get the idea.

It would be very helpful to plot the 3 histograms for image1, image2 and the equalized histogram to see how the intensity levels for image1 are changed.

Comment: @Ramo My mistake. I've updated the last line of code; let me know if it works with whichever of the two alternatives you prefer.

Comment: Its ok I figured it out; I have basically used your method, but first I have converted both images to hsv then at the end converted it back to rgb; this has worked just fine. One more last question; if you could explain how the code exactly works please. Thanks for your help mate!

Comment: Yeah, this code assumes you're using HSV images. If you use RGB then channel 3 is Blue instead of Value(Intensity). I'll add a little more information about `imhist` and `histeq` in the answer.